# Shooting video in bright light

Tags: lighting

I usually shoot photos using the view finder (eye cup). When I shoot video, I need to use live view and in bright areas, such as a beach, when I look into the monitor all I see is myself. So obviously I can't focus. Is there an easy remedy for this?

Comment: Look for an LCD hood? https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1129189-REG/elvid_ov_50_optiview_50_3_2_lcd.html

Comment: TY. Could be just the thing I need.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a plastic, often foldable cover to go over your LCD screen similar to what Hasselblad camera's and other top level viewfinder camera's would have.

You could easily craft one yourself from black paper just to experiment with it without spending much. If you have a Nikon I know they have plastic LCD protectors that snap on to the back LCD. You could make something attached to that cover so you don't have to stick anything on the camera itself.

If you're fine with that solution you can look for a product made specifically for your camera model in any online or IRL photography related shop.

Looks like this product snaps on the back of a Nikon LCD like that (note that I have no experience with the product or seller whatsoever, just as an example):

[image]

from [https://www.amazon.com/LCD-Protector-Camera-HOOD-Nikon-D500/dp/B07598DFM8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07598DFM8)